# Should I use "all the five" or "all five"?

Tags: word-usage, articles, definite-article

Here is a sentence I wrote in my thesis in which I felt there is something strange with "all five". I assume I should improve it by using "all the five", right?

*(I have explained the five prosodic parameters before)...*

> "... tests of between-subjects effects indicated that the influence of Attitude type was significant on all five prosodic parameters."

Answer (score 2):

All five is OK.  We don't use "the" before a number when we use all.

Comment: Thanks， but is there any other problems， as you know， I felt it strange somewhay and do not know exactly.

Comment: You could also say "tests of between-subjects effects indicated that the influence of Attitude type was significant on all *of the* five prosodic parameters." if you really want the "the" in there.

Comment: Ping, be sure. There are no problems. We say all 20 students, all 5 women, all four procedures. etc.